# how to use SharpSSH for Executing linux commands which prompts for additonal input?

Tags: c#, ssh, console, sharpssh

Ok heres what I'm trying to do

I have to setup an SSH session to a linux machine and issue a command like "ls" or cp.

heres the snippet

```
            SshStream  ssh = new SshStream ("myhost","root","pass");
            ssh.Prompt ="#";
            ssh.RemoveTerminalEmulationCharacters = true;
            byte[] byt = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("rm vivek");
            Array.Resize (ref byt,byt.Length +3 );
            byt[byt.Length-1]=(byte)'\r';
            byt[byt.Length - 2] = (byte)'y';
            byt[byt.Length - 3] = (byte)'\r';
            ssh.Write(byt);

            Console.WriteLine(ssh.ReadResponse());
```

The thing is commands like **"ls"** are simple you type it and it gives the output, but commands like **rm**

require addtional acknowledement like an "y"

as you can see from the above snippet the code essentially generates a bytes sequence like

**rm vivek [enter] y [enter]**

But it doesnt work, it is as if it is still wating for the input at

```
[root@host ~]# rm vivek
rm: remove regular file `vivek'?
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Hope the question is clear.

P.S I have tried the SSHExec sample again the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do `rm vivek -f` to avoid the confirmation ?

Otherwise, just expect the question and answer it before reading the response:

```
 ssh.Write(byt);
 ssh.Expect("rm: remove .*");
 ssh.WriteLine("y");
 Console.WriteLine(ssh.ReadResponse());
```

Comment: Brilliant Idea!  +1 But it only solves the problem with "rm" what if I'm configuring a router and I have to talk to an IOS where commands doesnt always have these options... thats my fundamental problem..Please dont get me wrong,I'm just explaining my problem

Comment: You have to think of it as a dialog. You send something, you expect something, you send something else, etc.