# Get file size from SFTP using SharpSSH

Tags: c#, console-application, sftp, sharpssh

I'm uploading a zip file from local directory to SFTP using SharpSSH. Everything works fine.
However, I would like to get the file size of the current file I just uploaded. The reason I'm doing this is that the zip file is big (from 45 GB to 80 GB) and I want to make sure that during the upload it didn't fail or stuck. Want to make sure the entire zip is uploaded.

I can get the file size of the local zip file like this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(yesterdaysArchiveFolder);
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo f in files)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Size of the zip file: " + f.Length);
}
```

Now, I want to do the same thing for the file I just uploaded to SFTP after the upload is complete.

Since I know the name of the file I just uploaded I create an `ArrayList` and put the files from SFTP. I then use `for loop` to get the file I just uploaded.

```
ArrayList FileList = oSftp.GetFileList(_ftpDirectory);
int count = FileList.Count;
Console.WriteLine("Files in SFTP: " + count);

for (int i = 0; i < FileList.Count; i++)
{
     if (zipFileName == FileList[i].ToString())
     {
       Console.WriteLine(FileList[i]);          
     }
}
```

The problem is that there're no properties like `.Length` to get the file size of that file?

Is there another approach I can take to find out the file size of the file in remote server?

Comment: As you have an SSH connection, I would think you could execute commands like `ls` on the remote server. Here's an example (although it concerns something slighty different) of doing that: [how to use SharpSSH for Executing linux commands which prompts for additonal input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857788/how-to-use-sharpssh-for-executing-linux-commands-which-prompts-for-additonal-inp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharpSSH does not allow that. But you can code it as SharpSSH is open source.

See my answer to another SharpSSH question [Download file based on date modified from SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25543826/850848).

---

Though SharpSSH is a dead project, you should use another SFTP library:

- [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) has the method `SftpClient.ListDirectory` returning the `IEnumerable<SftpFile>`. The `SftpFile` has the `.Length` property;
- [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) has the method [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory) returning (via the `RemoteDirectoryInfo.Files`) a collection of the [`RemoteFileInfo`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotefileinfo) with the property `.Length`.
  *(I'm the author of WinSCP .NET assembly)*

Comment: I'll accept this as an aswer, since I had no choice but to switch the library. I went with [Kellerman Software](http://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-41-net-sftp-library.aspx?mode=Specifications&). Thank you.